# Malformed XML in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

After a few hours of hair-tearing, I finally got WP8 to write to an xml file...simpler than I originally thought.

Now though, the structure of the generated document is not as intended.

```
XDocument tagRegistry = new XDocument(new XElement("SmartSafe"));

        if (stringUid == "" | desiredName == "" | latitude == "" | longitude == "" | stringUid == null | desiredName == null | latitude == null | longitude == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong....Please try again in a moment...");
        }
        else
        {
            tagRegistry.Element("SmartSafe").Add(new XElement("Tag", 
                new XAttribute("tag", stringUid), 
                new XAttribute("name", desiredName), 
                new XAttribute("latitude", latitude), 
                new XAttribute("longitude", longitude)));
        }
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("/tagRegistry.xml"))
            {
                tagRegistry.Save(stream);
            }
        }
```

This generates the following XML File.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SmartSafe>
      <Tag tag="2" name="Home" latitude="53.8975533333333" longitude="-1.94872666666667" />
    </SmartSafe>
```

What I was intending, was along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SmartSafe>
  <Tag>
    <tag>2<tag>
    <name>Home</name>
    <latitude>12345<latitude>
    <longitude>12345<longitude/>
  </Tag>
</SmartSafe>
```

How can I change my code to correctly generate the file?

Comment: For something like this I'd use a serializable object and serialize to xml from those objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.  You are creating attributes on an Element

Use XElement instead of XAttribute.

Comment: Ahh! Perfect, thank you! Figured it would be something I'd overlooked...Thanks

+1 Beer

Comment: Another quick question...currently, the xml file is overwritten with each new item. How do I append rather than overwrite?

Thankyou

Comment: instead of creating a new blank XDocument every time, use XDocument.Load() to read the existing file into a document, then add the new nodes onto that document.